# How to merge JSON arrays from multiple files via jq with order preserved

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm attempting to setup a hierarchy of JSON configuration files where defaults can be overridden at multiple levels. Each file is a set of key/value pairs. There are many of these organized by function in non-alphabetical order.

I've found a method to get the logical result I want, but it's sorted in alphabetical order, and due to the number of expected parameters, it will be hard for the user to clearly/quickly see if the set is what they want before using it.

Is there a way to perform this sort of merge, replacing values on matching keys and preserving order?

I have these files:

default.json:

```
[
  { "ParameterKey": "FirstStackName",  "ParameterValue": "Production-App-Database" },
  { "ParameterKey": "SecondStackName", "ParameterValue": "Production-Directory" },
  { "ParameterKey": "ThirdStackName",  "ParameterValue": "Production-VPC" },
  { "ParameterKey": "FourthStackName", "ParameterValue": "AMIFunctions" },
  { "ParameterKey": "FifthKeyName",    "ParameterValue": "administrator" },
  { "ParameterKey": "SixthUserName",   "ParameterValue": "admin" },
  { "ParameterKey": "SeventhPassword", "ParameterValue": "" }
]
```

environment.json:

```
[
  { "ParameterKey": "FirstStackName",  "ParameterValue": "Development-App-Database" },
  { "ParameterKey": "SecondStackName", "ParameterValue": "Development-Directory" },
  { "ParameterKey": "ThirdStackName",  "ParameterValue": "Development-VPC" },
  { "ParameterKey": "FifthKeyName",    "ParameterValue": "developer" }
]
```

user.json:

```
[
  { "ParameterKey": "FifthKeyName",    "ParameterValue": "jdoe" }
]
```

secure.json:

```
[
  { "ParameterKey": "SeventhPassword", "ParameterValue": "secretvalue" }
]
```

If I run this:

```
jq -s '.[3] + .[2] + .[1] + .[0] | unique_by(.ParameterKey)' default.json environment.json user.json secure.json
```

I get something that works:

```
[
  { 
    "ParameterKey": "FifthKeyName",
    "ParameterValue": "jdoe"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "FirstStackName",
    "ParameterValue": "Development-App-Database"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "FourthStackName",
    "ParameterValue": "AMIFunctions"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "SecondStackName",
    "ParameterValue": "Development-Directory"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "SeventhPassword",
    "ParameterValue": "secretvalue"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "SixthUserName",
    "ParameterValue": "admin"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "ThirdStackName",
    "ParameterValue": "Development-VPC"
  }
]
```

But (imagine 60 params) it's not easily scanned as correct, and what I want is this:

```
[
  { "ParameterKey": "FirstStackName",  "ParameterValue": "Development-App-Database" },
  { "ParameterKey": "SecondStackName", "ParameterValue": "Development-Directory" },
  { "ParameterKey": "ThirdStackName",  "ParameterValue": "Development-VPC" },
  { "ParameterKey": "FourthStackName", "ParameterValue": "AMIFunctions" },
  { "ParameterKey": "FifthKeyName",    "ParameterValue": "jdoe" },
  { "ParameterKey": "SixthUserName",   "ParameterValue": "admin" },
  { "ParameterKey": "SeventhPassword", "ParameterValue": "secretvalue" }
]
```

Comment: Is `default.json` guaranteed to have a superset of the keys found in other files?

Comment: It could be made to. Not sure if there's an alternative. If you haven't guessed, this is to pass in a parameters array to an AWS CloudFormation template. That's in YAML, and has the complete set with defaults. So, ideally, I'd only want to pass in the environment, user and secure overrides, as defaults are in the template itself. But, don't think that's simple to do.

Comment: I haven't guessed -- I build a product that ships on physical hardware, and don't have any experience with CloudFormation. That said, nothing about what you're describing seems hard to me, but I'd need a proper reproducer to test against if what's provided in the question doesn't suffice to accurately represent the real case.

Answer (score 1):

`unique_by` entails a sort, so the simplest would be to use `INDEX` (uppercase):

```
[INDEX(inputs[]; .ParameterKey)[]]
```

I've used `inputs` here to avoid all the disadvantages of the -s option, but remember to use the -n option instead.

In case your jq does not have INDEX, you can use this def:

```
def INDEX(s; f):
  reduce s as $x  (null; .[$x|f] = $x );
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy thing to do is to build a map from the keys to the values (combining all the input sources in turn), and then go back and reprocess `default.json`, applying that generated map.

```
jq -n --slurpfile template default.json '
# generate an unordered key:value dictionary
([inputs | .[] | {(.ParameterKey): (.ParameterValue)}] | add) as $map |

# apply those pairs to the template to get its ordering
[ $template[0][] | {"ParameterKey": (.ParameterKey), "ParameterValue": ($map[.ParameterKey])} ]

' default.json environment.json user.json secure.json
```

...which properly outputs:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "FirstStackName",
    "ParameterValue": "Development-App-Database"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "SecondStackName",
    "ParameterValue": "Development-Directory"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "ThirdStackName",
    "ParameterValue": "Development-VPC"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "FourthStackName",
    "ParameterValue": "AMIFunctions"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "FifthKeyName",
    "ParameterValue": "jdoe"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "SixthUserName",
    "ParameterValue": "admin"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "SeventhPassword",
    "ParameterValue": "secretvalue"
  }
]
```

...retaining `default.json`'s ordering.

---

If you *insist* on having the whitespace just so, one way to do it is by piping output of the above through the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
pieces=( )
while read -r line; do
  case $line in
    "["|"]")       printf '%s\n' "$line";;
    *(' ')"}"?(,)) printf '%2s %-35s %s %2s\n' "${pieces[@]}" "$line"; pieces=( );;
    *)             pieces+=( "$line" )
  esac
done
```

The above is careful to only change whitespace, and to not recognize any delimiters other than newlines; as such, its output should always be semantically identical to its input. See https://ideone.com/EI0RuJ as a demonstration of this code working in practice, with output of:

```
[
 { "ParameterKey": "FirstStackName",   "ParameterValue": "Development-App-Database" },
 { "ParameterKey": "SecondStackName",  "ParameterValue": "Development-Directory" },
 { "ParameterKey": "ThirdStackName",   "ParameterValue": "Development-VPC" },
 { "ParameterKey": "FourthStackName",  "ParameterValue": "AMIFunctions" },
 { "ParameterKey": "FifthKeyName",     "ParameterValue": "jdoe" },
 { "ParameterKey": "SixthUserName",    "ParameterValue": "admin" },
 { "ParameterKey": "SeventhPassword",  "ParameterValue": "secretvalue"  }
]
```

Comment: This is great! Very close to what I was looking for, and without the algorithmic code I was expecting. I did play around with running the out of this through some sed commands to get it closer: (code above) | sed -e '/{$/N;s/\n   //' -e '/^  {.*,$/N;s/\n   //g' -e '/^  {.*$/N;s/\n //' - now only lacking column alignment.

Comment: I very much frown on using syntax-unaware tools to modify JSON, but if you *must*, the answer is amended.

Comment: (The other thing is that including formatting along with jq work is really bifurcating this question, moving it away from being an entry in a knowledge base of "here are canonical answers for specific and narrow questions" -- which we strive for -- and towards being a "please write my code for me" question, which we don't generally welcome at all).

Comment: Charles - thanks for going the extra mile, as I realized I was probably crossing the line a bit with my request to format the JSON output and probably should have asked that in a "sed" group. I could have written a script like you provided (thank you), but was hoping there was a non-algorithmic method in sed or awk I was not aware of. And, I thought others might be interested in a way to align JSON Key/Value arrays, as it's pretty common.

Comment: Plus, I'm not aware of a tool that IS JSON syntax aware which allows folding of the default indented format that while standard, tends to produce long but narrow output which is not as easy for humans to read as when certain line combinations as I've asked for are done. Most enterprise-class CloudFormation JSON examples from AWS, for example, combine lines to increase readability in this manner. If you're aware of a tool that can combine JSON lines through some type of configuration file, I'd love to use it instead!

Comment: Sure -- the only legitimate (ie. non-personal-ideology) grounds I have to object to the whitespace-formatting question is it being combined with the other question about semantics. Split it into two narrower questions (one about ordering, the other about formatting), and I have no space on which to (legitimately) complain. BTW, I'd tend to look towards tools that process JSON content as token streams rather than objects as the general space where you're most likely to have more control of whitespace/formatting surrounding those tokens' emission.